# Combining EXISTS and LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join, left-join, exists

I need some help combining two queries I wrote( I do not know if it is possible to do it or not). But first let me show you the table and exaplin it so there are no ambiguous angles here.

This is the table I have (PS : I do not know how to make decent looking tables in StackOverflow even though I researched it, and tried to use Senseful solutions so please excuse the image) :

[Main Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ur8HN.png)

The first query I have is the following :

```
SELECT *
FROM Dropship As t1
WHERE t1.HUB_SO_GOODS_ISSUE_DATE IS NULL 
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Dropship t2
WHERE t2.LE_PO = t1.LE_PO
AND t2.HUB_SO_GOODS_ISSUE_DATE IS NOT NULL);
```

This query gives me all orders that have not have been fully processed. So with the table I have it gives me the orders (LE_PO) 300 and 500 like in the following image :

[result from first query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtyvb.png)

Another query I use is the left join one :

```
SELECT Dropship.*, Notes_Replenishment.*
FROM Dropship LEFT JOIN Notes_Replenishment ON Dropship.LE_PO = Notes_Replenishment.LE_PO;
```

The notes_replenishment table has all the orders (LE_PO) but also comments put in by a user. What I would like to do is to incorporate the left join in to the first query so that it gives me the result (see above) but also the comments from the Notes_replenishment table however I get errors when I tried doing it by myself.

Could somebody give me some pointers on how to combine the two queries?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Dropship As t1
LEFT JOIN 
        Notes_Replenishment
ON      t1.LE_PO = Notes_Replenishment.LE_PO
WHERE   t1.HUB_SO_GOODS_ISSUE_DATE IS NULL 
        AND EXISTS 
        (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    Dropship t2
        WHERE   t2.LE_PO = t1.LE_PO
                AND t2.HUB_SO_GOODS_ISSUE_DATE IS NOT NULL
        )
```

Comment: Thank you very much Andomar! I didn't think it would be that simple and feel kind of ridiculous now but your help is appreciated fully! :)